# Is it possible for a child process to read a file which is locked by parent process?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a Parent process which creates a file using [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) and locks it. below is the code:

```
m_hWriterLockFile = ::CreateFile("C:\\Test.txt", 
                             GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                             0, // exclusive
                             NULL, // default security
                             OPEN_ALWAYS,
                             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                             NULL);
```

Now, I want only the child process to access this locked file. I do not want any other process to read this file.

I have created a child process. Below is the sample code:

```
// Initialize a security attributes structure.
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    if (!CreateProcess("FileReader.exe", // I want to invoke this exe
    "C:\\Test.txt",
    &sa,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi))
{
    std::cout << "Create Process Faild (%d) " << GetLastError() << '\n';
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to achieve my goal, is there anyone who can help me? Is there any other way to achieve this? I will share more information(code) if needed.

Note: I didn't share the complete code to make the post shorter.

Comment: *"Is there any other way to achieve this ?"* - Possibly. But since you explained your solution rather than the *real* problem you are trying to solve, there's little we can do but guess.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that ChildProcess is not able to read the File which is locked by its parent process.

Comment: The file isn't locked in any way. It's just opened without any sharing permissions. Locking and sharing are different concepts. Regardless, you still haven't explained what problem you are trying to solve. This is just asking to get your current solution working (which may or may not be appropriate in context of your problem).

Comment: I agree, using "Lock" word is not appropriate .Basically when we install our application a .kix file gets crated temporarily in the "temp" folder. .kix file contains scripts in plain text and user can access this temp file before it gets deleted and can modify the scripts and can do bad things. 
Hence , I am trying to create the file in such a way that no one can access except the child process .

Comment: That's not how you secure data. If you need to make sure the file hasn't been tampered with, digitally sign it and verify the signature. Now of course, if you don't care enough to implement proper security, you could just `DuplicateHandle` the file handle into the spawned process, and take it from there. Unrelated to this question, make sure you understand to consequences of passing both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` into `CreateProcess`. Also make sure to understand that you're calling `GetLastError` too late for it to report a meaningful value.

Comment: thanks. I believe that we cant't do much with the .kix file because "WKIX32.EXE" is the one who process the .kix file and unfortunately KiXtart is close source.
http://www.kixtart.org/.

I did not understand completely  "you could just DuplicateHandle the file handle into the spawned process, and take it from there"

Comment: If all you want is prevent users from *modifying* the file, then why aren't you opening it with the `FILE_SHARE_READ` sharing permission? [Duplicating the file handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle), as suggested above, only works, if you actually access the file by file handle. Presumably, you're passing the file *name* into WKIX32.EXE, so that's not an option then.

Comment: It is not about the modifying the file, User can copy that temp file within 1 secs . and then they can run the scripts later. basically there are some scripts in kix which can call COM APIs and modify the registry or FS
Yes you are write, below is the partial code for childProcess 

CreateProcess("WKIX32.EXE,", 
    "C:\\.......\\temp\\xyz.kix,
    &sa,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi))

Comment: It's not at all clear, what problem you are really trying to solve here. If you want to prevent the user from making changes to the registry, then how are you going to undo the fact, that Windows ships with regedit.exe? If you want to prevent users from making changes to the file system, then how are you planning to undo the fact, that Windows ships with File Explorer? If people want to brick their system, then they have all the tools available to do so.

Comment: The `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` control the handle being created, so you need to set inheritability when you do the `CreateFile`, so that the file handle is inheritable. (You are setting inheritability on the `CreateProcess`, which makes the process handle inheritable, but you don't care about the process handle.) You also have to communicate the value of the file handle to the child process somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of of my question :

create the file with an inheritable handle and pass that handle to the child process. A simple way to do this is to pass it as a command line parameter. We must pass a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure that specifies TRUE for bInheritHandle to CreateFile and also pass TRUE to the bInheritHandles parameter of the call to CreateProcess.

**Create File**

Ex:

```
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa{ sizeof sa, nullptr, TRUE };
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Test.txt",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    &sa,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
```

**Child Process:**

```
UINT_PTR uiHandle = reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(hFile);

        sprintf_s(szCmdLine, "\"%s\" %Iu", szExePath, uiHandle);

        if (CreateProcessA(nullptr,
            szCmdLine,
            nullptr,
            nullptr,
            TRUE,
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            nullptr,
            nullptr,
            &si,
            &pi))
        {
           CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
           CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

        }
```

Comment: This will work, unfortunately it's really bad practice to create inheritable handles because they are shared with *every* child process, not just the one you wanted to share with.  Better to follow the documentation note "Applications can use the `UpdateProcThreadAttributeList` function with the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` parameter to provide a list of handles to be inherited by a particular process." and list each inheritable handle explicitly.